# Statement specific auditing - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, audit

I have enabled default auditing in one of my database. Oracle 11g. Audit_trail is set to DB, other than that for a particular schema 'test' I have set:

```
audit all on test by access
```

With the above setting, I know I can get to know what action has been performed (alter,create,update,etc) but will I be able to fetch the SQL statments (all DML operations) with the exact SQL statement fired from that schema from the audit records? Let me know how?

If the above is not possible, what is required to fetch the exact SQL statement that is run by the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AUDIT_TRAIL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams017.htm#REFRN10006)

If you want the SQL text to be captured, you need to use the `extended` option for `audit_trail` (`db, extended` or `xml, extended`).

`alter system set AUDIT_TRAIL=db, extended scope=spfile;`

or

`alter system set AUDIT_TRAIL=xml, extended scope=spfile;`

Changing this setting requires a database restart to take effect.

For FGA you can specify a different audit trail, for example: `audit_trail => DBMS_FGA.DB_EXTENDED`, that way you can leave `audit_trail` on `DB`. If you use FGA, you do not even need to use `AUDIT`, just create the policy you need.

Comment: Won't FGA help in meeting my requirement without changing it to xml?

Comment: @tesla747 You do not need to change it to XML, there is `db, extended`. Updated my answer for FGA.

Comment: As mentioned here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_FGA -- this should simply work right? No need to change to extended or XML. Simply create a policy on a schema to capture everything, it will work right?

Comment: @tesla747 That is what I wrote also.